# Args.slice is not a function in a Discord bot

Tags: discord.js

I'm new in this, I need a little help. I'm doing Discord bot, I know is silly but I like this. My problem is to do a command with a function, when I execute this command in the console I get this:

`TypeError: args.join is not a function` or `TypeError: args.slice(...).join is not a function`

(Are two possibilities)
I don't know what are the problem. Anyone can help me
Thanks.

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

```
if(!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send('You can\'t use that!')
if(!message.guild.me.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send('I don\'t have the right permissions.')

const member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);

if(!args[0]) return message.channel.send('Please specify a user');

if(!member) return message.channel.send('Can\'t seem to find this user. Sorry \'bout that :/');
if(!member.bannable) return message.channel.send('This user can\'t be banned. It is either because they are a mod/admin, or their highest role is higher than mine');

if(member.id === message.author.id) return message.channel.send('Bruh, you can\'t ban yourself!');

let reason = args.slice(1).join(' ');

if(!reason) reason = 'Unspecified';

member.ban(`${reason}`).catch(err => { 
  message.channel.send('Something went wrong')
    console.log(err)
})
```

Comment: Help us help you - share your code

Comment: `args` must be an array